# Shared Deployment Groups across team projects in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Is it possible to share Deployment Groups across team projects in VS Team Services?

I have a few logically different team projects sharing the same servers. I would like to create one instance of deployment groups and share it across team projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no way for this to span projects. In VSTS, very little spans projects for a variety of reasons such as security and pipeline management. Due to the way the pipeline works in VSTS, I don't think they will ever let this span multiple projects. You could always suggest it in the [VSTS User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services) forum or get a more detailed explanation as to why not.